# Windows 8 kiosk

Tags: windows, windows-8, web-development, kiosk

I need to lockdown windows 8 for a kiosk using chrome.  I have tried some of the paid solutions out there but none of them support chrome.  Has anyone accomplished this without purchasing a product?

Setup:

- Windows 8
- Touch screen
- Google Chrome with --kiosk flag

Comment: @bacord - There is no paid or free solution at this time.  It will be added by the end of the year with the `Windows 8.1` update.

Answer (score 4):

Wait for Windows 8.1 which will be released as a free Update later this year. This will allow to provide a kiosk mode for the new store apps (use the "metro" version of Chrome):

[image]

http://withinwindows.com/within-windows/2013/4/23/blues-clues-enabling-kiosk-mode

Comment: I wish this was an option, but I need a solution this week.  I will likely upgrade to this option once 8.1 is released.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: If you use Windows 8 Enterprise you can use **AppLocker** to allow only chrome to be executed. Now put a shortcut of chrome.exe into the startup folder.