# Is there any way to remove the Windows 8 start on the right side in touch screens?

Tags: windows, windows-8, kiosk

I am attempting to create a kiosk using Windows 8, but the menu that pop ups on the right side when one slides one's fingers in that area is an issue.

Comment: MSDN: [Create a Kiosk Sample Windows 8 App (Standard 8)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj979593%28v=winembedded.81%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Wait for Windows 8.1 to get the [official kiosk mode](https://superuser.com/a/604207/174557):

[image]

Comment: This is probably the best solution, however the asker may not have time to wait.

Comment: the preview will be available at BUILD in 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

That's called the "Charms Bar", and the menu that appears with white icons whenever you hover over it is called the hint. I found [this](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-charms-bar-hint-in-windows-8/) guide which explains disabling that "feature".

Just remember that if there is access to the keyboard or on-screen keyboard the charms bar can still be accessed with <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: There is no access to the keyboard

Comment: I followed the guide. It removed the bar for the mouse but not for touch.

Comment: After some searching, I found that [this](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.103) program will disable the charm bar for touch screens.